# how can i trigger another job using build parameter in jenkins and using variable parameters

Tags: jenkins, build, parameters

```
build (job: 'software_installation_pipeline', parameters: [
            file(name: 'hostname', file: 'hostabcnew'),
            string(name: 'software_name', value: 'software'),
            string(name: 'server_domain', value: String.valueOf(server_domain)),
            string(name: 'administrator_server_address', value:String.valueOf(administrator_server_address))
            ])
```

I am having an issue with Fileparameters is there any way to replace this and take file as an input in jenkins pipeline (i do notice there is an open issue 27413, looking for AN alternative solution)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options that are a bit of a hack.
Store the file somewhere else such as S3 and pass a reference to the file instead. Use archiveArtifact to archive the file in the first Jenkins build and have the triggered build retrieve the artifact.
Use Artifactory as a file conduit.

Comment: Thanks for the idea